# Is there any way to make it mandatory to use some specific annotation along with some particular method in Java

Tags: java, annotations

A class implementing interface ensures that all the methods in the interface are defined in the class, likewise, is there any way to tell the JVM that some specific annotations should be used in implementing class. Consider the following interface

```
public interface TestClass{
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup();
    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown();
}
```

and following is the implementing class

```
public class TestScripts implements TestClass{
    @BeforeClass
    public void setup(){
        /*method body*/
    }
    @AfterClass
    public void tearDown(){
       /*method body*/
   }
}
```

All I want is that the compiler should show error if `@BeforeClass` annotation is not used with the method `public void setup()` and `@AfterClass` annotation is not used with the method `public void tearDown()`. Any way to achieve this?

Comment: Google's Errorprone does a similar thing with per-test (not per-class) `setup` methods http://errorprone.info/bugpattern/JUnit4SetUpNotRun - you could write a similar checker for this.

Comment: Note that methods annotated `@BeforeClass`/`@AfterClass` need to be static too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't enforce this but what you can enforce is that a sub-class implements an abstract method.

```
public abstract class TestClass {
    @BeforeClass
    public void beforeClass(){
        setup();
    }

    protected void abstract setup();

    @AfterClass
    public void afterClass(){
       tearDown();
   }

    protected void abstract tearDown();
}
```

and then any sub-class has to implement these methods and they will be called based on the annotation.